# How do you integrate $\int \int \sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)}dy dx$ without using polar coordinates ?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int \int \sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)}dy dx$ without using polar coordinates (i.e. only in rectangular coordinates )?

I tried u substitution -

$u = 1-x^2-y^2$

$du = -2x-2y$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @vadim - sorry I forgot the square root

Comment: Try subbing $y = \sin\theta$.

Comment: Are you trying to integrate a definite integral or indefinite integral?

Comment: @JackyChong - I am actually trying to compute a definite integral, but for the purposes of this problem I just need to know how to start it without using polar coordinates.

Comment: Could you write out the bounds? Because we might be able to figure out the volume using geometry.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}dy dx$ without using polar coordinates

Comment: So are all of you guys saying there is no way to do this using rectangular?

Comment: I think it is a waste of time to not use polar coordinates, but using my substitution above is not using polar coordinates and may be fruitful.

Comment: maybe $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\sin\theta$ is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\int^1_{-1}\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ dydx = \int_{D} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ dA
\end{align}
where $D$ is the unit disk. Observe the graph of your function
\begin{align}
z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} 
\end{align}
is the ball which means the volume is just
\begin{align}
\int_{D} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ dA= \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3
\end{align}
where $R=1$.

Comment: Hi Jacky - I marked your answer correct because this is the way I did this problem when I first saw it.  This is basically a half sphere and if you know  the volume of the sphere is $4/3 \pi r^3$ then this problem is easy.  I was wondering if there is another way to do this problem without using polar coordinates, but I guess there isn't.